# Excel Web Services email javascript worksheet

Tags: javascript, web-services, excel

Is it possible to get the current content of an excel javascript worksheet and email it.  There is a download button that allows you to download the worksheet with its current content, but I cannot find the code that does this, if I could I would be able to email it, any help to get an instance of the worksheet to email as an excel file would be great thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with saving it and using a file attachment?

Comment: Nothing, the client wants it that way

Comment: excel web services is part of microsoft's skydrive microsoft office web app api

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the snapshot feature
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms519570

write the snapshot to your email attachment (MAPI) or load it to a file for attaching.

Comment: Not exaclty what I was looking for, notice how the question states that this is the javascript worksheet.  I am trying to do this using javascript.  The server is a php server anyways, I do not believe php will be able to access the information because the actual worksheet is stored on skydrive as stated above